# React component rendering only component tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It loads index.html successfully with no js errors but nothing is rendered to the page. Nothing rendering in the webpage. it only shows  tag when I inspect the webpage.
I have a component called "list".

list.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class list extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default list;
```

I imported it on App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import list from "./components/list";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <list />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Use capital letters for component names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you, App.js capitalized your List in your third line and tenth line.and also you can use eslint-config-airbnb to find this kind of error.

(eslint-config-airbnb is npm preset)

more details - https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb

Answer (score 7):

[User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Because it's not capitalized, the renderer takes the `list` tag as an HTML tag. Not as a React Component.

Answer (score 2):

In you App.js, capitalized your List in your third line and tenth line.